# Method overloading doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, overloading

I have a method **setAddress($town,$zip.$coord)** defined in my class **User**. In the same class User I have the **__call** setter 'set' which is called when my method is called with only one parameter(ex: setAddress($town)). The problem is that when I call the method with one parameter : setAddress('New York'), I have an error('Missing parameters'). If i call it with 3 parameters the overloading is working. Why the __call function is not called if the method is called with 1 parameter?

User.php

```
namespace com\killerphp\modells;
class User{
    protected $address;
    protected $firstName;
    protected $lastName;
    protected $email;

public function setAddress($town,$zip,$coord){
    echo "I have 3 arguments";
}
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    $prefix=  substr($name, 0, 3); //get,set
    $property=substr($name, 3);    //address,firstName,email etc
    $property=lcfirst($property);

    switch($prefix){
        case "set":
            if(count($arguments)==1){
                echo 'asa i';
                $this->$property=$arguments[0];
            }

            break;
        case  "get":
            return $this->$property;
            break;
        default: throw new \Exception('magic method doesnt support the prefix');


    }





   }
}
```

Index.php

```
    define('APPLICATION_PATH',  realpath('../'));
    $paths=array(
        APPLICATION_PATH,
        get_include_path()
    );
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$paths));

    function __autoload($className){
        $filename=str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $className).'.php';
        require_once $filename; 
        }

    use com\killerphp\modells as Modells;
    $g=new Modells\User();
    $g->setAddress('new york','23444','west');
    echo($g->getAddress());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premise of the question is wrong: PHP, like most other dynamic languages, has no function overloading.

When you specify the name of a function that's what is going to get called; the number and types of the arguments do not play a part in the decision.

You can approximate the desired behavior by supplying default values for some arguments and checking the argument situation at runtime, e.g.:

```
public function setAddress($town, $zip = null, $coord = null) {
    switch(func_num_args()) {
        // the following method calls refer to private methods that contain
        // the implementation; this method is just a dispatcher
        case 1: return $this->setAddressOneArg($town);
        case 3: return $this->setAddressThreeArgs($town, $zip, $coord);
        default:
            trigger_error("Wrong number of arguments", E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jon.OK, so __call magic method is not used to overload some methods, but to use it as for variadic functions and dispatching them to other functions. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But the most common use case for `__call` is to enable objects to define methods at runtime.

Comment: @Jon.Is very interesting because I study a book named "Mysql 5.4 and Mysql 5.5",german(http://www.amazon.de/MySQL-Objektorientierung-Webanwendungen-PHP-Frameworks-Performancesteigerungen/dp/3836218763/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1383832458&sr=1-1&keywords=Stefan+Reimer) and this magic method is under the subtitle "Methods overloading" :)